# Driver Templates, Minimum Kernel Distro., drivers community, driver for Microcontroller?

Tags: c, linux, templates, kernel, driver

I am post-newbie to Embedded Linux driver development, have developed Character, UART & simple USB drivers, and have worked with SBC (Raspberry Pi 2). My main learning resources are: Essential Linux Device Drivers, Embedded Linux System Design & Development, youtube tutorials and LDD3. Because of lack of real life driver experience, I have some questions that I would like to share:

1. Templates: are there some sort of driver templates for speeding up the coding process e.g. have the regularly used structures & functions for being modified & customized for the specific drivers.
2. What’s suitable minimum distribution:
   What I am doing now is either building a kernel image using Buildroot then inserting the developed USB driver into it OR inserting the developed USB driver into a Ubuntu. And for proper testing I have to unload the default USB driver (usb_storage); otherwise can’t test my module. So, my question is regarding real-life development & how-to get minimum kernel that has no drivers, & how-to include my module into it (to be part of it) while building with Buildroot?
3. What Embedded Linux Driver Development community do you suggest for detailed Q&A?
   i.e. In future if I want to ask about low level detail such as what is this x structure, or I am getting this error while using this y function .... is there a specialized community?  because all I found are for Linux in general, for Kernel hacking, or don’t have experiences.
4. What is the missed link in the chain?
   Developing applications for Microcontrollers relies on Datasheet, User Guide, Registers, C, etc. Developing Drivers for Embedded Linux relies on C, Linux API, Subsystems, etc. In most learning resources, I never found a relationship between both. So, are there really separated? OR there is a missed link between them??

e.g. for this I2C sensor http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/srf10tech.htm  we have to manipulate it (send hexa to & receive values from its registers). If we imagine that we want to develop an I2C driver for it, then for sure we would need to do the same from within the driver, which is explained in Essential Linux Device Drivers (page#278). The main point behind it is that I2C core hides many complexes & simplifies driver development process.

However, I expect the case in real life is not for a sensor, instead it might be a Microcontroller or a complicated device. So, how would we manipulate the Registers & Peripherals of this Microcontroller? Also, I didn’t find tutorial for such a case!

Comment: 2. `make tinyconfig` or `make localmodconfig`